# NodeJS - Training material

Tags: node.js

I wanted to check if anybody knew of good resources to learn more on Node.js such as books, etc..

If there are any sites that are good resources that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

[learnyounode](https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode) helped me alot.

I also heavily advocate for CodeSchool. They have an awesome Node course

Answer (score 0):

Node.js alone is very basic, it's basically a JavaScript run-time. To really learn node you need to learn some of the major packages used in nodejs applications such as express. I recommend going to [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) or [npmdiscover](http://www.npmdiscover.com/) and find packages you find interesting and look into those.

When that is said there are some good tutorials on learnyounode. Personally i have learned a lot from courses on Pluralsight.